# Is json more performant than a javascript object?

Tags: json, reactjs, performance

I am making a quizz. All the questions are stored in a json file, and displayed dynamically in a React component. However, this only allow me to add text. What If I want to pass a render prop (an icon instead of a text for example)? I would need to use a javascript object.

Performance-wise, is there a big gap between loading a 500 lines json and a 500 lines javascript object with render-props?

Comment: The best answer to performance questions is usually "try it both ways in your real code and see whether it matters" and/or "worry about performance if and when you see a performance problem in real code."

Comment: "Lines" doesn't really tell us much (a "line" can be megabytes long), but if I assume you mean 500 lines of normally-formatted JavaScript or JSON, then:  Forget about it, not going to make any difference you need to worry about.

Comment: @BrianThompson - No, JavaScript syntax is dramatically more complex than JSON syntax (which is a subset of it specifically designed for quick parsing), so parsing JavaScript code generally takes longer than parsing JSON.

Comment: @tjcrowder thanks, I appreciate the correction

Comment: So in the end, I've just added a special string to the label when I wanted an icon: label: "icon_iconname", and added the component afterwards if label.startsWith("icon"). This way I can keep the json format.